# Add indented text to yaml file with python

Tags: python, yaml, indentation, ruamel.yaml

I have a YAML file to which I want to add and replace some missing arguments and I am passing them from another YAML file, but the final product looks like this:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: ms
spec:
    template:
        metadata:
            annotations:
                cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict: 'true'
        spec:
            containers:
               -  name: ms
                  command: [npm, run, start:prod]
                  resources:
                      requests:
                          memory: 256Mi
                          cpu: 150m
                      limits:
                          memory: 512Mi
                          cpu: 150m
                  readinessProbe:
                  livenessProbe:
livenessProbe:
    failureThreshold: 3
    httpGet:
        path: /LIVENESS
        port: PORT
        scheme: HTTP
    initialDelaySeconds: 30
    periodSeconds: 2
    successThreshold: 1
    timeoutSeconds: 1
```

I need the text with the livenessProbe: header to replace the one with the new values with the respective identation. This is an example of the python code I am using:

```
from posixpath import abspath
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import yaml
import os
import sys

pathroot = os.getcwd()

os.system('clear')

text = "requests:"
notext = "failureThreshold:"

with open('template-live.yaml', 'r') as file:
    resourceslistlive = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

with open('template-ready.yaml', 'r') as file:
    resourceslistready = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

def searchText(path):

    findString = False

    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        content = f.read()
        if text in content:
            findString = True

        if notext in content:
            findString = False
        f.close()
    if findString:
        with open(path, 'a') as fileA:
            yaml.dump(resourceslistlive, fileA)

        with open(path, 'a') as fileB:
            yaml.dump(resourceslistready, fileB)

name = "patch-resources-limit.yaml"
archivos = 0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(pathroot):
    if name in files:
        searchText(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Comment: So what is the problem you're having?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd recommend taking a look at the [tour] and [ask] as you find your bearings. Thank you for including your code, but in situations like this, you don't necessarily need *all* of it, verbatim. A lot of what you've shared (walking directories, testing file contents, etc.) doesn't directly relate to your question, so a [mrE] would leave those out.

Comment: Also you're importing `ruamel.yaml` *and* `yaml` (two different packages), but only using one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the existing `livenessProbe` with a new one, stop thinking of this as a text file. It's a YAML file that can be unmarshalled into a Python data structure, and then you can simply replace the value of a key.

Assuming we have the original deployment in `deployment.yaml` and the updated `livenessProbe` in `livenessprobe.yaml`, like this:

```
livenessProbe:
    failureThreshold: 3
    httpGet:
        path: /LIVENESS
        port: PORT
        scheme: HTTP
    initialDelaySeconds: 30
    periodSeconds: 2
    successThreshold: 1
    timeoutSeconds: 1
```

Then we can perform the update like this:

```py
import yaml

with open("deployment.yaml") as fd:
    deployment = yaml.safe_load(fd)

with open("livenessprobe.yaml") as fd:
    probe = yaml.safe_load(fd)

deployment["spec"]["template"]["spec"]["containers"][0].update(probe)

print(yaml.safe_dump(deployment))
```

Which produces as output:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ms
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict: 'true'
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - npm
        - run
        - start:prod
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /LIVENESS
            port: PORT
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 2
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: ms
        readinessProbe: null
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 150m
            memory: 512Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 150m
            memory: 256Mi
```

---

If you're trying to read the `livenessProbe` from another complete deployment manifest, then that update statement might look like this instead:

```
deployment["spec"]["template"]["spec"]["containers"][0]["livenessProbe"] = \
  livenessprobe["spec"]["template"]["spec"]["containers"][0]["livenessProbe"]
```

---

For patching YAML deployment manifests, I would consider [`kustomize`](https://kustomize.io/) as an alternative to writing your own patching code; given you original deployment in `deployment.yaml` and a patch file `livenessprobe.yaml` that looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ms
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ms
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /LIVENESS
            port: PORT
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 2
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
```

You would create a `kustomization.yaml` that looks like this:

```yaml
resources:
- deployment.yaml

patches:
- path: livenessprobe.yaml
```

And then running `kustomize build` would produce the desired output.

Note that support for `kustomize` is built into the `kubectl` command.

Comment: `print(yaml.safe_dump(deployment))` first has PyYAML stream the output to a `StringIO` buffer, then does get the value of that buffer and then streams it out to `sys.stdout`. That is memrory inffecient and slow. You should directly stream to stdout: `yaml.safe_dump(deployment, sys.stdout)`

Answer (score 1):

Your output includes a block sequence that is the value for `containers`, and it is indented six positions
with an offset for the dash of three. You cannot get that output using PyYAML, but you can with `ruamel.yaml.`

The "replacement" should be done by loading both datastructures, searching throught the data structure **and not
through the text of the YAML file**, updating the datastructure at the position found, and then dumping the datastructure
back to YAML. That guarantees you have correct YAML as the output, e.g. with regards to indentation,
which is very hard for all but the most simple text replacment.

Assuming your input YAML file `template-live.yaml` consists of the first 23 lines of your input
and the `template-ready.yaml` of the rest:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

def replace(d, key, value):
    # recursively searches d for key, replaces first time found only
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if key in d:
            d[key] = value
            return True
        for k, v in d.items():
            if replace(v, key, value):
                return True
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for elem in d:
            if replace(elem, key, value):
                return True
    return False

template_path = Path('template-live.yaml')
substitute_path = Path('template-ready.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=6, offset=3)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(template_path)

# assumes root of YAML is a mapping and that keys are unique in template
for key, value in yaml.load(substitute_path).items():
    if not replace(data, key, value):
        print(f'did not find {key} in {template_path}')
        sys.exit(0)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: ms
spec:
    template:
        metadata:
            annotations:
                cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict: 'true'
        spec:
            containers:
               -  name: ms
                  command: [npm, run, start:prod]
                  resources:
                      requests:
                          memory: 256Mi
                          cpu: 150m
                      limits:
                          memory: 512Mi
                          cpu: 150m
                  readinessProbe:
                  livenessProbe:
                      failureThreshold: 3
                      httpGet:
                          path: /LIVENESS
                          port: PORT
                          scheme: HTTP
                      initialDelaySeconds: 30
                      periodSeconds: 2
                      successThreshold: 1
                      timeoutSeconds: 1
```